# Android - Connect to MSSQL online database

Tags: android

I'm new to Android programming. I have a website with sql 2008 db, and now i would like to give the users the ability to use their smart phones to enter data to this db.
I was wondering what is the best way to establish it. Since I'm new to it I don't want to build something that's not so professional.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The right answer for me was to use KSoap library. I'ts very easy and works very well.
Here is a tutorial that will show you how to do it step by step.

http://java.dzone.com/articles/invoke-webservices-android

Answer (score 2):

If I were you I would consider two following options:

1. Have a web application optimised for mobile use;

   Pros:

   - Updates are delivered immediately, as there's no client application, everything is done on the server;
   - Web application can be used on many devices with a browser and not just Android: iPhone, Blackberry, PC, Mac, etc.;

   Cons:

   - Users need to be online to work with the application;
   - You can not leverage from the native UI components available to native device applications;
2. Write Android application that will work with the database via a number of REST endpoints exposed through a web application (again);

   The pros and cons are a full reverse of what you had in the first option.

Comment: You have a very good point, but this way i'll never learn how to program for android :).